# HostnameVerifier = AllowAll for WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.xx

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I built an API using Micro Integrator and it is calling an internal API endpoint with self-signed certificate. I am having this error message

```
ERROR_CODE : 101500,ERROR_MESSAGE :Error in Sender,ERROR_DETAIL : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host : app-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local\n\tat org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:182)\n\tat org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:371)\n\tat org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n
```

Is it possible to configure the Micro Integrator to allow all for the hostname verification? I added this on my deployment.toml and still encountering the issue. This is the same code block that I added on my APIM deployment.toml to disable hostname verification.

```
[transport.passthru_https.sender.parameters]
HostnameVerifier = "AllowAll"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following configuration in the deployment.toml of MI.

```
[transport.http]
sender.hostname_verifier = "AllowAll"
```